# What's wrong with my code? (Threejs spotlight shadow)

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I created a scene in Three.js, with two cubes on a plane. The spotLight is located over the top-left corner, and it should be look at the given coordinates 50, 0, -50.

The shadows look strange, and the light doesn't look at the given coordinates (I tried `light.target.position.set`, and `light.lookAt`)

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/5gNvr/

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing the fov of the light to 75.

```
light.shadowCameraFov = 75;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But the light doesn't look at the given coordinates (I tried `light.target.position.set`, and `light.lookAt`)

Comment: I think Spolight behaves a bit like a Pointlight at the moment. We haven't been able to make it behave as expected yet.

Comment: I've found it! `light.target = cube`

Comment: light.target.copy( cube.position )

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong:

```
cube.position = {
    x: -50,
    y: 15,
    z: 50
};
```

*position* is a *Vector3* and you're replacing it to an *Object* losing all its methods (which the light may rely on).

Do this instead:

```
cube.position.set( -50, 15, 50 );
```

This may or may not fix your issue.